# D3 Javascript library and time functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I used the D3 library ver < 4.4.4 for quite a long time and now I moved to the latest one (4.4.4).

I used to call this function:

```
d3.time.format()
```

looks like the `.time` object doesn't exist anymore, what's the 4.4.4 equivalent?

**EDIT**

I noticed they now use `d3_time`, is that another library I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.time.format` is now `d3.timeFormat`.

This, and other time functions, have been changed.  See [this link](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#time-formats-d3-time-format).